# Copying and Replacing Values with Values Within the Same Variable Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, group-by

Sorry if the title is not specific enough, I'm imagining it in excel terms. I have a dataframe:

```
           Product             Group             ...        Score_Alpha      Score_Beta
0           XXX0X1             Cinnamon          ...         0.007598         0.007538
1           XXX0X2             Cinnamon          ...         0.007598         0.007538
2           XXX0X3             Cinnamon          ...         0.007598         0.007538
3           XXX0X4             Cinnamon Special  ...         0.003343         0.002696
4           XXX0X5             Cinnamon Special  ...         0.003343         0.002696
5           XXX0X6             Cinnamon Special  ...         0.003343         0.002696
6           XXX0X7             Peach             ...         0.003399         0.004444
7           XXX0X8             Peach             ...         0.003399         0.004444
8           XXX0X9             Peach             ...         0.003399         0.004444
9           XXX0X10            Peach Special     ...         0.006677         0.006262
10          XXX0X11            Peach Special     ...         0.006677         0.006262
11          XXX0X12            Peach Special     ...         0.006677         0.006262
```

I need to replace the Score_Alpha and Score_Beta of lines where Group =='Cinnamon Special' with that of 'Cinnamon', the same between 'Peach Special' and 'Peach'. Basically, it should look like this:

```
           Product             Group             ...        Score_Alpha      Score_Beta
0           XXX0X1             Cinnamon          ...         0.007598         0.007538
1           XXX0X2             Cinnamon          ...         0.007598         0.007538
2           XXX0X3             Cinnamon          ...         0.007598         0.007538
3           XXX0X4             Cinnamon Special  ...         0.007598         0.007538
4           XXX0X5             Cinnamon Special  ...         0.007598         0.007538
5           XXX0X6             Cinnamon Special  ...         0.007598         0.007538
6           XXX0X7             Peach             ...         0.003399         0.004444
7           XXX0X8             Peach             ...         0.003399         0.004444
8           XXX0X9             Peach             ...         0.003399         0.004444
9           XXX0X10            Peach Special     ...         0.003399         0.004444
10          XXX0X11            Peach Special     ...         0.003399         0.004444
11          XXX0X12            Peach Special     ...         0.003399         0.004444
```

My apologies if this sort of question has already been answered, my googling skills are questionable.

I have about 30+ unique values in Group with their own 'XXX Special' counterparts so I cannot manually group by specific values in the variable

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the value of Score_Alpha and Score_Beta where Group =='Cinnamon'

```
scores = df.loc[df["Group"]=='Cinnamon',["Score_Alpha", "Score_Beta"]].iloc[0].tolist()
```

Second, put the scores to df where Group =='Cinnamon Special'

```
df.loc[df["Group"]=='Cinnamon Special', ["Score_Alpha", "Score_Beta"]] = scores
```

In the same way,

```
scores = df.loc[df["Group"]=='Peach',["Score_Alpha", "Score_Beta"]].iloc[0].tolist()
df.loc[df["Group"]=='Peach Special', ["Score_Alpha", "Score_Beta"]] = scores
```

Because there are 30+ unique values in Group with their own 'XXX Special', you can solve it with a function

```
# First, extract all group names without "Special"
names = [x for x in set(df["Group"].tolist()) if "Special" not in x]

# Second, define a function
def replace_values(df, name):
    scores = df.loc[df["Group"] == name, ["Score_Alpha", "Score_Beta"]].iloc[0].tolist()
    df.loc[df["Group"]== name + ' Special', ["Score_Alpha", "Score_Beta"]] = scores

# Third, iterate name in names
for name in group:
    replace_values(df, name)
```